# LWJGL GLSL shader not compiling

Tags: opengl, glsl, lwjgl

I am using the lastest recomended version of LWJGL 3, and while trying to compile shaders i get errors.

Shader:

```
#version 330

in vec2 position;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Error:

```
Vertex shader failed to compile with the following errors:
ERROR: 0:1: error(#307) Invalid profile "in"
ERROR: 0:1: error(#76) Syntax error: unexpected tokens following #version
ERROR: 0:1: error(#364) Invalid: unexpected token in symbol.
ERROR: error(#273) 3 compilation errors.  No code generated
```

I wasnt able to find anything related to this error online. Does anyone here know?

Comment: Try `#version 330 core`. This should be default, but well. Also are you sure that your setup supports 3.3?

Comment: How do you read on the shader? Looks as if the end of line characters (`\n`) are missing in the string which means that the compiler treats the in keyword as profile qualifier for the `#version` directive.

Comment: My PC supports up 4.4. Version 330 core doesnt exist, at least it says it doesnt.

Comment: @BDL that was it thanks, please post it as answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks as if the end of line characters (`\n`) are missing in the code string which means that the compiler treats the `in` keyword as profile qualifier for the `#version` directive.